# How can I put a selected item in a php post array with javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to post a selected item from a dropdown list on one php page so that I can access in another php page.  The page does not have a submit button so I am using javascript at the bottom of the page.  Here's the page that should put the item in post.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <?php session_start();?>
 </head>
 <body>

     <select class="myList" name="Country" id="country-selector"  autofocus="autofocus" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Select Country</option>
       <option value="Belgium" data-alternative-spellings="BE België Belgie Belgien Belgique" data-relevancy-booster="1.5">Belgium</option>
      </select>

  <Script>

  $(function () {

  $("#country-selector").change(function(){

  var x = document.getElementById("country-selector").value;

   alert(x);
   $.post('page2.php', {'selectedCountry': x});
   $.post('page2.php','val='+$(this).val(),function (response){

  alert(response);
  }); 

  });

  });
   </script>

   </body>
   </html>
```

Then I want page2.php as the target page.  I go to page2.php and try to view the post array like this:

```
   <?php
  session_start();

  echo $_POST['selectedCountry'];

    print_r($_POST);

  ?>
```

...but the selectedCountry item is not in the $_POST array.  How can I put a selected item in a php post array with javascript?
Thanks.

Comment: $_POST['selectedCountry'] will contain the value in your first ajax post, but you do not have an alert statement in it. In the second ajax post request, $_POST will not have the "selectedCountry " key so you will get output like Array("val" => "Belgium"). What is your problem?

Comment: I'm just using the alert statements for debugging purposes.  What I want is to have the selected item put into the  the $_POST array then access it in another page.

Comment: @CloudyKooper Thats now how POST variables work, they are only available on the current request. If you need to access them on another page request you need to save them to a session or a database of some kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $("#country-selector").change(function(){

  var x = document.getElementById("country-selector").value;

   $.post('page2.php', {'selectedCountry': x}).done(function(response) {
      alert(response);
  });

  });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! as this is your first answer, it comes for review.  Generally - code only answers are usually better with a little context. While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide some explanation for why it does so.

Comment: Sorry about my question being confusing.  The final result I want is to get the name of the selected country from the post and assign it to a session variable.  Like  $_SESSION['selectedcountry']=$_POST['selectedCountry'].  Only I can's seem to get the name of the selected country in the post array so that I can then put it into a session array.